# Sprite collides with unknown object and rotates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my unity 5.3 2D project I have a sprite that uses a vector3 lerp function to move from one location to another on the x axis.But for some reason my map which contains colliders in a maze format causes the sprite to collide with an unknown object and therefore it rotates. I have tried fixing the colliders and seeing if it was any other gameobject that caused the collision but as far as I know a collider is causing the problem. The sprite is able to fit perfectly between colliders but after a some time this problem occurs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(360,166,0);
private Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(656,166,0);
public float speed = 1.0f;

void Update() {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (pos1, pos2, (Mathf.Sin(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by unknown objects , you can't see The objects?

Comment: If you disable collider on your object - then everything is ok? Also you can restrict rotation of your object for different axes, on rigidbody component.

Comment: By unknown objects I mean untagged objects. I tagged every object that I imported except the colliders on my map @MiladQasemi

Comment: For restricting rotation would I have to freeze position Z? @Vladimir